Why is My Application Icon Not Appearing in the System Tray on Windows 11, but it Works Fine on Windows 10?
I have added my application to the userinit key in the Windows registry, and the application icon appears in the system tray without any issues on Windows 10. However, when I attempt the same setup on Windows 11, the application icon does not appear in the system tray.
